# Reflection and Transmission of String Waves

Tags: waves, boundary-conditions

I was recently studying Waves and I came across a derivation of Amplitudes of reflected and transmitted waves in a string.

[image]

Why have they used the highlighted conditions for the derivation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It tells you that at $x=0$ where the incident and reflected wave added together from the left and the transmitted wave from the right meet, there can't be any discontinuity. So they must be equal at $x=0$. Therefor:

$$y_1+y_2|_{x=0}=y_3|_{x=0},\\
\Rightarrow A_i\sin(\omega t)+A_r \sin(\omega t)=A_t \sin(\omega t), \\
\Rightarrow A_i+A_r=A_t.
$$

Comment: which positions does x = 0 implies ?

Comment: Its the position where the incident wave reflects and transmitts. For example the interface between two different media with different refractive index $n$.